# Cant get the value of props send to child class component when used with if function to render

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am creating a login page with API key in reactJS. User should enter API key to get logged in.

the problem is I have sent the API key entered to the child component as a prop. And for the testing process, I tried to console.log API-key in the child component. but I get undefined.

submain functional component

````
       {
           props.login?<div><h1>Login:{props.login}</h1><Fetchapi apiID ={apiID}/></div>: <div className="mbox">
           <h3>{props.message}</h3>
       </div>    
     }```

child component(very bid showing necessary part)


```class Fetchapi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      datas:[],
      more_leads:true,
      show:false,   // for modal toggling
      currentPage:1,
      rowsPerPage:10,
      clickedData:{
        "First Name":"",
        "Last Name":"",
          "Email":"",
          "ID":"",
          "Country":"",
          "Mobile":""
        }
      };
      this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
      this.handlePrevious = this.handlePrevious.bind(this);
      this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
      this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
      // Modal Funtions

    }

and many more codes 
-
-
-
componentDidUpdate() {


  fetch(req)
    .then(response=> response.json())
    .then(users => {

        if(this._isMounted)
        {
          this.setState({ datas: users.response,
          more_leads:users.is_more_leads_available
        })
      }


    });

  console.log("apiID from fetch",this.props.apiID)  ;// this code gives undefined in console.log

}


I even tried to render in the DOM
```<h1>{this.props.apiID}</h1>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem my self. There was another component rendering the same child component and I passed the props through that component and it worked.